# How to disable keyboard play button for Keynote

Tags: keynote

I use music through Spotify while presenting. I want to move completely to Keynote from PowerPoint but one of the things keeping me from doing so is that the play button on the keyboard starts and stops the presentation in Keynote as opposed to starting/stopping music in Spotify. Is there anyway to remove this key binding from Keynote?

Answer (score 1):

What I am reading here is that you want to..

- Remove and/or replace the key binding in Keynote that starts/stops a presentation
- Remap that keybinding to Spotify

There is a program that does it, it's called [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/).  It will allow you to remap keybindings at the application level.

Comment: This looks promising but also very confusing. I've downloaded it and I can't see how to enable/disable program specific.

Comment: I don't use Spotify or Keynote, so I can't do yours specifically, but you can remove the keybinding for Keynote by using a filter for the app:  https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en#appdef

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no solution to this.